# C: Trying to create a character device in Linux

Tags: c, ubuntu, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to create a character device in Linux that will be able to read/write what the user supplies into a buffer. I have so far:

```
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *file, 
           char __user * buffer, /* buffer to be filled with data */
           size_t length,  /* length of the buffer     */
           loff_t * offset)
{
int i,getout;
getout = 0;

for(i = bufferindex; i < length; i++)
{
    if(put_user(Message[bufferindex],buffer) != 0)
    {
        printk("put_user failed\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }
    bufferindex ++;
    if(bufferindex == strlen(Message))
    {
        getout = 1;
        bufferindex = 0;
    }
    if(getout)
        break;
}


return i;
}

 static ssize_t
 device_write(struct file *file,
     const char __user * buffer, size_t length, loff_t * offset)
{ 
int i;
bufferindex = 0;
printk("device_write(%p,%d)\n", file, (int)length);

for (i = 0; i < length && i < BUF_LEN-1; i++)
    if(get_user(Message[i], buffer + i) != 0)
    {
        printk("get_user failed\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }

Message[i+1] = '\0';
/* return the number of input characters used */
return i;
}
```

How do I test if it's working (I loaded the driver and used mknod, but how do I read/write and check if it's working?) Also, how can I detect a user trying to get me to write from a corrupt buffer?

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Write to it by using e.g. `echo 'hi device!' >/dev/whatever` where `whatever` is the device node. Read using `cat /dev/whatever`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Apparently both read/write don't work. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed the read. Is there a way to detect if a buffer is corrupt?

Comment: Both `put_user` and `get_user`, aside from copiing data, also checks user space buffer: if it points outside of user-process data, these functions return positive value. It is already checked in your code.